# Midnight Commander: shell link connection not show dirs

Tags: shell, ssh, openssh, mc

Everything works fine when the target computer is windows 10 with cygwin and openssh 5.9p1-1 (libopenssl098 0.9.8t-1) [computer1].

After upgrading cygwin with openssh 1.1.1t-1 (libssl1.1 1.1.1t-1) [computer2], after connecting via `Shell link`, folders are not displayed and cannot be opened.

computer2:
`cd home` -> Cannot chdir to "home" Permission denied (13)
the creation of the folder is successful, but it does not appear in the panel and cannot even be opened. After checking directly on the target computer, it does exist.
Attempt to connect via SFTP link: sftp: failure establishing SSH session (-5)

computer1: both shell link and sftp link work

Direct use of the `sftp user@IP` command will be successful and folders and files will also be displayed via `ls`

Where is the problem?